# How to run multiple parallel AJAX calls in Jquery without waiting until all AJAX calls are finished

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two parallel AJAX calls, the first one `boost()` does some text processing which takes about 20 seconds. The second one `progress()` should update on the progress until the first AJAX call is done.

$.when() allows me to run parallel AJAX calls, however the response is only output if both AJAX calls are finished.

I want to start both AJAX calls at the same time, while `boost()` runs, `progress()` should output the progress every second.

That's what I got so far, but `progress()` only outputs after `boost()` is finished:

```
$('#booster').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.when( boost() ).then( progress() );
});

function progress() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get('/progress.php', function(prog){
      $('#progress').html(prog);
    });
  }, 500);
}

function boost() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/boost.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id: id,
      task: 'boost'
    }, success: function(data) {
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: AJAX calls are by default ran in parallel, being asynchronous. `$.when` does something else: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using $.when, this is what is causing `progress` to run after the `boost` call. It is the same as placing it in the `success` method.

Instead, make both calls together as Cristy mentioned since it is already async, then in the success callback simply clear the interval.

```js
var interval = null;

$('#booster').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  boost();
});

function boost() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.get('/progress.php', function(prog) {
      $('#progress').html(prog);
    });
  }, 500);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/boost.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id: id,
      task: 'boost'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this output the progress only after the boost function is finished, not while it is running?

Comment: So, what happens now in my code is that the progress is displayed after the boost() function is done. But it displays all progress numbers at once in a quick sequence. Seems like the progress was executed properly during the boost, but didn't show up one by one progress step.

Comment: did you disable async in jquery? try adding `async:true` to the $.ajax call. the other option is to make the `boost.php` kick off a process on the server and return immediately.